# How to check string is a file?

Tags: php

I have stored file names and datas in single 'comment' column in database. I want to check the string is file or not. If it is file, then I need to show file link. I tried

```
var_dump(is_file('path/filename'))
```

This always shows `bool(false)` as output even in `image.jpg` file. How to check the string is file or not?

Comment: You need to give the correct path ?

Comment: Yes. I checked the path too. @Luuk

Comment: Try to do this: `var_dump(is_file('/usr/bin/bash'))`  It should return `bool(true)` on most (linux) systems.

Comment: _"I have stored file names and datas in single 'comment' column in database."_ - Why not have separate columns for different type of data instead?

Comment: I just think we can identify using is_file() or any other functions like this @M.Eriksson

Answer (score 0):

You can do with glob function

```
$result = glob("./path/filename.*");
```

Answer (score 0):

The php functions, like `is_file()`, taking path arguments, handle absolute (starting with `/`) and relative pathnames differently.

Relative pathnames like your `path/filename` example use the path of your php program as a starting point. So if your php program is in `/var/www/code/foo.php`, your example looks for `/var/www/code/path/filename`. It seems unlikely you want that.

**Edit** Files you serve to your audience via your web server have two pathnames. For example.

1. `https://example.com/img/flower.jpg` is its URL, visible to the audience,
2. `/var/www/img/flower.jpg` is its pathname in the file system of the server machine.

`is_file()` uses the second one.

You didn't tell us enough about your server's file system layout or the paths you store in your database for us to suggest a definitive fix to your problem.

Comment: `http://localhost/project/uploads/img.jpg` this is the path where I stored image. I give this path statically as well as dynamically `var_dump(is_file(base_url('uploads/').$comment['comments']));` @O. Jones

Comment: Please never post question details as comments.  You should edit your question so that the full story is all in one place.